# Foursquare: "hereNow" missing in Userless auth?

Tags: php, api, foursquare

i'm new to foursquare API. I'm trying to make it work wioth my wordpress website (listing directory, like venues) and for each venue I want to display the "hereNow" users along with photos and reviews/tips.
 I've registered my app and so I have both client id and secret.
for tips/photos I think i cant do without Auth, but I wonder why herenow is missing from my array.
this is the query i've used on my php file:

```
$venue = $fsObjUnAuth->get('/venues/search', array('near' => $city, 'query' => $title ));
```

where

```
$fsObjUnAuth = new EpiFoursquare($clientId, $clientSecret);
```

and city and title are taken from Wordpress custom fields.

I got the correct ouput but herenow is missing, here an extract:

```
   ["verified"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["stats"]=>
      object(stdClass)#20 (3) {
        ["checkinsCount"]=>
        int(1)
        ["usersCount"]=>
        int(1)
        ["tipCount"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      ["likes"]=>
      object(stdClass)#21 (2) {
        ["count"]=>
        int(0)
        ["groups"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["specials"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
```

It is supposed to be below Specials but no trace. In the Api Explorer it appears regularly, but on my files not. 
Any hint?

thanks!

Comment: hmmmm the documentation says "required ID of venue to retrieve" I'm not using the ID of the venue, just the Query name, so that's why

Comment: Can you look at the underlying herenow object in the JSON returned by the foursquare API? There does appear to be a herenow block returned there so this might be an issue with your parsing library (see https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fll%3D40.7,-74 for a sample query which does show the herenow block)

Comment: Yes, as i said, it DOES shows up in the API Explroer, but not on my query

Comment: That means that you're not properly parsing the returned object. Alternatively, capture the outgoing url you're making to the API and run it manually in a browser to view the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this adding the "v=" query at the end of the json url basically it is the date(Ymd) needed in the v2 API. with that, my output shows the hereNow

Comment: This answer helps, but only half. The other half I needed was the v=YYYYMMDD should be whatever date you tested with, the date you know that the FourSquare API was working so if 4Square changes their API they can try to give you the older logic. HTH.